# Entity Framework 5 Reverse Engineering and [Key] attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I'm reverse engineering a database with Entity Framework Power Tools beta 2, now, the POCOs created do not have the [Key] in the definition, but the mapping with Fluent has the  this.HasKey(t => t.EntityId);

I have the POCOs in a separate project and and MVC 4 application which has a reference to it. When I try to add a controller it says then entities do not have the Key defined.
Exact message is:

**System.Data.Entity.EdmEntityType: EntityType: 'Computer' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.**

Why the reverse engineering process do not add the [Key] attribute if it is mandatory? Or it is not mandatory and I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Comment: Maybe it's because you are using a beta tool.

Comment: There is no other than Beta as far as I'm concerned. But despite it is a beta, if that is mandatory, it's way easy to add, and being Beta 2, someone must have to ask this previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with connectionString to the database. Now I've the connectionStrings.config file set and it works.

NOTE: Worked to use reverse engineering but on runtime it fails again complaining about the [Key]
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Computer' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.